# Shouldn't a user who "favorite"s a question up-vote it?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, up-votes, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [If you bookmark a question, shouldn’t you also be encouraged to upvote it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/if-you-bookmark-a-question-shouldnt-you-also-be-encouraged-to-upvote-it)
>   [Why not get reputation when your question is marked a favorite by somebody?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/why-not-get-reputation-when-your-question-is-marked-a-favorite-by-somebody)

I see it quite often, a question has more users marked it as favorite than the users who upvoted it.

Isn't it somewhat, well, **(c)rude** to mark some question as favorite and **not** upvote it?, by marking it as favorite you say that this question **is** nice and useful.

Shouldn't users who mark question as favorite be encouraged to upvote it, too?
(Like when upvote an answer on your own question, a note is shown to remind you to accept it)

Comment: Somewhat ironic that this question has two favourites, and no up-votes.

Comment: Yes, funny :) (15 char)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/Why-not-get-reputation-when-your-question-is-marked-a-favorite-by-somebody

Comment: as Macha answered, but in my words, this is unnecessarily confusing, should just be bookmarks. And, I think your questioning is going towards Kudos definition, check my question, I think Kudos would be very useful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269777/why-no-stackexchange-site-has-kudos-voting-option

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*No*. Not everybody selects a question as his favourite because it's *really* their favourite. One could e.g. select it as a reminder to come back later to see whether people closed or reopened it. OR come back later to see whether the question has been improved. And sometimes a questions is not really good, but one of the answers is.

**Edit:** Ah, this question appears to be a duplicate of the slightly misnamed question [*If you bookmark a question, shouldn’t you also be encouraged to upvote it?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/if-you-bookmark-a-question-shouldnt-you-also-be-encouraged-to-upvote-it)

Answer (score 9):

I treat favourite as a bookmark - which has nothing to do with whether I think the question is any good or not.

This behaviour been noted elsewhere on meta - but I can't find the question again.

Actually either [the question in Stephan202's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/if-you-bookmark-a-question-shouldnt-you-also-be-encouraged-to-upvote-it) or [the one in Brad Gilbert's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/Why-not-get-reputation-when-your-question-is-marked-a-favorite-by-somebody) would fit the bill

Comment: I had that feeling as well, and I found the question. See my answer.

Comment: +1 I too use favoriting for bookmarking - and remove it when the question doesn't interests me anymore.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/Why-not-get-reputation-when-your-question-is-marked-a-favorite-by-somebody

Comment: @Brad Gilbert - thanks for finding that

Comment: I think many people misuses favorites as a way of "giving Kudos", what creates the problem of having several useless favorites (in a sense how favorites should be really used, like to continue a research later). I went towards a Kudos request, see what do you think? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269777/why-no-stackexchange-site-has-kudos-voting-option

Answer (score 8):

Stackoverflow and Internet Explorer have made the same mistake. They've called bookmarks "favorites".

(Yes, it wasn't the original intended use in SO's case, but it is what they have been used for)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "favorites" *faux pas*. I hated it when I had to bookmark some web page on tax code and call it a "favorite."

Comment: omg... that was the definition I was looking for!!! I created this question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269777/why-no-stackexchange-site-has-kudos-voting-option), and what you said clearly helps on it. Favorites should be renamed to bookmark, as a favorited thing means actually you really like it as a favorite thing, like we do when you praise or give kudos to someone!

Answer (score 1):

I sometime 'favorite' a question because I'm interested to see the answers, but I expect them to say something negative.

In other words, I may not think the question worthy of an upvote, but I want to be able to go back to it later. This is easier if it's a 'favorite'.

Answer (score 0):

People should be able to use the site as they want to some degree. Forcing users to vote when they perform other actions may be counter to their wishes.