# Shouldn't marking question as favorite be also "voting it up"?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If you bookmark a question, shouldn't you also be encouraged to upvote it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/if-you-bookmark-a-question-shouldnt-you-also-be-encouraged-to-upvote-it)
>   [Shouldn't a user who “favorite”s a question up-vote it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26297/shouldnt-a-user-who-favorites-a-question-up-vote-it)

First reaction - no, it shouldn't. But...

I have personally marked a lot of question as favorite, but I don't always reach out to vote them up, although all questions that I mark are favorite deserve a vote up from me, since I've found them noteworthy at least.

I miss on voting up by "automaticness" of actions and a habit to proceed fast while searching.

I am sure 99% of favorite marks are also naturally vote ups from the "marker". But this could be subjective. Please consider this idea.

Comment: Why? It's just a bookmark. You might want to keep an eye on a post to vote it up (or down) later.

Comment: Well, to vote up - may be, but to vote down? Based on what, how the questioner communicates? Voting down should not be used for punishment and if the question is bad, it's bad from the very beginning. Again, subjective opinion.

Comment: Honestly, I sometimes leave a comment asking for improvement / correction of a post, and then favorite it so that I remember to check back and downvote if they haven't fixed whatever the problem was.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov - if the post isn't improved, perhaps.

Comment: FYI: "Favorites" right now are sorta... useless. Expect... *changes.*

Comment: @Arjan, probably you are right. It is a duplicate discussion. By the way, what do I do in this case? Delete the duplicate. I mean what should I do on meta =)?

Comment: I honestly would aspect that every click on something in SO would produce rep somehow: gained or removed .. I would find it funny! Why not? Even if you bookmark a question to check later if it was improved, as said .. I find it gained your attention more than a question that you haven't bookmarked. So I would aspect a gain of rep too .. On another hand you could always vote down temporarily and bookmark a question to be improved and later on remove downvote and vote it up if it's been improved .. it could be an idea .. and downvote must be greater than bookmark up

Answer (score 1):

> I am sure 99% of favorite marks are also naturally vote ups from a marker.

Not necessarily.

If you think of favorite question as those you like most, yes, but you could also interpret favorite questions as bookmarked question.

There's a number of reasons to bookmark a question you wouldn't vote up, so an automatic upvote would be unfitting in those cases.