# Why do users favorite questions but not vote for them?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [If you bookmark a question, shouldn’t you also be encouraged to upvote it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/if-you-bookmark-a-question-shouldnt-you-also-be-encouraged-to-upvote-it)
>   [Questions with more favorites than upvotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38252/questions-with-more-favorites-than-upvotes)

If a user favorites a questions, they obviously like the question or want to be able to keep track of it. They would not normally do this for a question that they have no care for (positive or negative).

Yet users will often favorite a question without voting for it.

I really do not understand why?

If you are favoriting (is there a more correct word than favoriting?) it's because it's bad, and you want to track its status, and then downvote it.

If you are favoriting it because it's great, then up-vote it. Even if you feel it only pertains to you, that's still worth a vote indicating that it is of importance to someone other than the OP.

I have read in other discussions that it is much harder to get someone to vote on a question rather than an answer. Well, what if you cannot favorite a question until you have voted it (up or down)?

Comment: I'm going to favorite this question and not vote for it. Because it gives me giggles.

Comment: Ha... Why do I get the feeling this is going to be the question with 0 votes and the most favs... oh the irony.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19946/if-you-bookmark-a-question-shouldnt-you-also-be-encouraged-to-upvote-it, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38252/questions-with-more-favorites-than-upvotes...

Answer (score 7):

I favorite questions I think I can answer, but don't have the time to research right now.  Later on in the day, I will come back and if the question is still open, I will answer it and then possibly upvote the question.

Comment: A lot of great answers I never thought of, my suggestion probably is a bad idea. But I am glad I asked.

Answer (score 7):

One reason I can think of is they might be out of votes for the day.

Comment: Well that makes sense.. didn't think of that!

Comment: Ot they might be out of *close* votes for the day.

Answer (score 4):

I might favorite a bad question just out of perverse curiosity, or so that I can go back and see if it got closed.

Comment: Then you should down vote it... should you not?

Comment: @John Not necessarily. It might be a good question on it's own, but marginal for the site. I certainly don't down vote every question I vote to close. I mean, whats the point? Its just adding insult to injury.

Comment: I do the very same thing.

Answer (score 3):

It may be that the user is not sure how they feel about the question or doesn't have time to read/answer at this point, but wants to come back to it later, like a bookmark. I know I've done this several times.

In this case, mandating a vote in either direction is a bad idea, since votes are locked in after 5 minutes. After all, upon second reading, the user may realize that he/she miscomprehended the question initially because he/she was rushing.

Comment: Good point! ...

Answer (score 2):

I favorite some things that I'm interested in how they turn out in the long run, but I don't really support the issue (in Meta).

Answer (score 0):

I  do it because I view the question's votes as it's "score", and the star as a bookmarking mechanism.

The [Programmer Cartoon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) has 800+ votes, I like the question (starred it), but I don't vote because I think it's score is perfect as it is.

For an obscure "How do I ..." question with only a few upvotes, I might star because I wish to find it later for reference (I'm bookmarking it for later), and I feel it's +single digit score is sufficient for the question.

Comment: If you find it useful, why not upvote it? Especially an obscure question that would be hard to find elsewhere.

Comment: @mmyers: The programmer cartoon question is an obscure question that would be hard to find elsewhere?

Comment: I'm not talking about the cartoon question, of course. I was responding to the last paragraph. @Aar

Comment: @mmyers Because I have no opinion on whether the question is "good" or "useful" or not, I'm simply bookmarking it "just in case I might decide to use it later" (If I do use it later, I upvote it). And also because I usually the feel has a "good" score that meets the quality and value of the question already, I won't upvote it.

Comment: @rlb.usa: Ah, we have different theories of voting then. I try to vote on whether I think the post is good or not, not whether I think it's at the proper score.