# Allow favouriting a question only if you also upvoted it?

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, bookmarks

How is it possible for a question to having been favourited more often than upvoted? Shouldn't a question be a good question if you favourited it?

I think it would be good to restrict favourites only to people who felt that the question was worth it and so upvoted it. What do you think?

If you agree with the statement but not with the solution, do you know any better improvement?

Comment: Nope. I favorite a lot of bad questions just because they are funny. (Such as this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uQtcM.png)

Comment: I often favourite questions which are terrible to check back on them later to see if the OP improved them (especially if I commented suggesting improvements). What benefits would this restriction bring?

Comment: There is a million good reasons to favourite a question even though you don't feel it deserves an upvote. I think you can safely assume that the downvoters don't want the restriction you propose

Comment: I often favorite (terrible) questions so that I can come back and make sure someone didn't reopen them, or so that I can vote to delete in 5 days when it's eligible for deletion, or to see if someone actually applied the fix I suggested.

Comment: @Jerry you're suggesting I upvote questions I believe are bad so they improve?

Comment: Oh, and for the record, there could be, for example 5 upvotes, 4 favorites, all from people who upvoted, and 4 downvotes, leaving the post with 4 favorites and a score of 1.

Comment: @Jerry ok, so if I want to favourite a (currently bad) question I've suggested be improved so I can check back on it to see if it improves. But I can't because I haven't upvoted it. How do I proceed?

Comment: @Jerry Maybe, but that's their prerogative. I agree good stuff should be upvoted more, but taking away a useful feature from users to *enforce* that (even for content that may not warrant an upvote) isn't the way to go.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38252/questions-with-more-favorites-than-upvotes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The favorite link is often used by folks who simply want to access the question quickly and easily again. It doesn't always mean "*favorite*" as is commonly used. Perhaps it should be re-named.

> I think it would be good to restrict favourites only to people who felt that the question was worth it and so upvoted it.

Why? What purpose would this serve? I don't see a benefit to this.